# Pointers with STL maps and lists

Tags: c++, class, stl, iterator

I did do a good search on the 'net about this and turned up lots of help regarding vectors but not really anything on STL lists.  I am attempting to erase a pointer from a list within a map. (a little tricky).  I really want to use pointers and not revert to another (worse) system of doing things.  I will show the code

```
bool RoomDB::removePlayer( int socketid, int roomid )   {

list<GamePlayer>::iterator itit;

 for( itit == roomlist[roomid].playerlist.begin(); itit != itit.end(); itit++ ) {
    if( itit.socketno == socketid )
    itit.erase( itit );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it should just be like this:

```
roomlist[roomid].playerlist.remove_if(
    [socketid](GamePlayer const & gp) { return gp.socketno == socketid; }
);
```

If you don't have lambdas, you'll have to write a little predicate yourself, or you go the manual way; but now beware of the loop:

```
for (std::list<GamePlayer>::iterator it = roomlist[roomid].playerlist.begin();
     it != roomlist[roomid].playerlist.end();  /* no increment */ )
{
   if (it->socketno == socketid)
   {
     it = roomlist[roomid].playerlist.erase(it);
   }
   else
   {
     ++it;
   }
}
```

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Thanks, took me forever to understand what was going on :-S

Comment: Sorry for this offtopic comment, but could you recommend a book or something to learn all the stdlib classes and everything from? Effective STL is both outdated (now that we have C++11) and for people who already know the STL decently. I know the datastructures and a few algorithms, but my knowledge of the stdlib is painfully lacking. Like in this case, I knew there was a way to do this with `remove_if` because I've seen it around SO, but I had no idea how to do it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Check our FAQ, there's a "good books" post somewhere. I think Herb Sutter has a few books that explicitly go through the library containers, though I haven't got/read it. Or just read [the standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft), sections 23/24/25; or browse one of them reference websites, or ask in the SO chat! :-)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Check out channel 9 , STL has a lot of videos regarding the new standards, and what VC 2010/2011 support. He has an excellent intro to the Standard Template Library video series, I suggest you check them out.

Comment: @johnathon: [Link #1: STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-10-of-10), [Link #2: ASTL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-6-of-n). Links contain further links to all episodes. Seth: Yes, STL is a [real boy](http://nuwen.net/stl.html).

Comment: Many thanks both of you, I can feel the templatised power coursing through my veins already.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong. I will try to list all of them, though I may miss some:

1. It should be `list<GamePlayer*>::iterator itit;` if, as you say, your lists contain pointers
2. It should be `itit = roomlist[roomid].playerlist.begin();`, not `itit = ...`, like KerrekSB said
3. It should be `itit != roomlist[roomid].playerlist.end()`, not `itit != itit.end()`
4. It should be `if( (*itit)->socketno == socketid )`, not `if( itit.socketno == socketid )` (again, if your list contains pointers)
5. It should be `roomlist[roomid].playerlist.erase(itit)`, not `itit.erase(itit)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but my pointer system is all buggered.  I'm just going to go with a serial approach ( referancing with int's instead of pointers, nevermind)  You all seem very intelegent so thanks for the help!